# Apache RewriteRule match anything not matching

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to proxy traffic without Apache messing up urlencoded path content. In searching about this problem, I found this solution

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[a-zA-Z]+ /foobar/(.*) HTTP/\d\.\d$"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:3333/foobar/%1 [P,L,NE]
```

So anything coming into /foobar/ should be proxied to localhost on port 3333. I'm not having much luck.

```
10.36.163.39 - - [04/Dec/2013:15:32:21 --0500] [10.38.200.253/sid#11037e0][rid#117cd68/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri   /foobar/msl/v1/configuration/
10.36.163.39 - - [04/Dec/2013:15:32:21 --0500] [10.38.200.253/sid#11037e0][rid#117cd68/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/foobar/msl/v1/configuration/'
10.36.163.39 - - [04/Dec/2013:15:32:21 --0500] [10.38.200.253/sid#11037e0][rid#117cd68/initial] (1) pass through /foobar/msl/v1/configuration/
```

The proxy isn't happening because the RewriteRule apparently doesn't match, but it should match anything, should it not?

Comment: Delete the RewriteCond, and use this `RewriteRule ^/foobar/(.*)$ http://localhost:3333/foobar/$1  [P,L,NE]` . Just curious, are you sure you need `AllowEncodedSlashes`?

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. Urlencoded characters are still being decoded with that config. That's the whole point of matching %{THE_REQUEST}. http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding#UsingApachemodrewritecorrectly

Comment: Well, then maybe you could make your `RewriteCond` a little less restrictive like this `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "/foobar/(.*) "`?

Comment: But it seems as if the rewritecond is matched, and the rewrite engine is then attempting to apply the rewrite rule, which is then failing. I'll try that though.

Comment: Actually, I think that worked, and it passed the request through without modifying it!

Comment: Just for posterity, it's possible that rewritecond wasn't being logged. RewriteCond is logged as trace4 where the example provided in the docs is trace3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have mod_proxy loaded. The `P` flag won't do anything unless you have mod_proxy loaded and it's not always loaded by default on most installations.
2. If you are doing this in your server/vhost config, consider just using mod_proxy by itself. `ProxyPass` (and `ProxyPassMatch`) essentially does what you're trying to do, and you can also reverse proxy the cookies and redirects as well:

   ```
   ProxyPassMatch ^/foobar/(.*)$ http://localhost:3333/foobar/$1
   ```

Comment: Again, basic ProxyPass does not fix the problem of url encoding and decoding. ProxyPass is inherently broken to me, in that it is modifying the request and passing it on modified. The nocanon option is being ignored, so that doesn't help. The apache logs explicitely tell me that nocanon is ignored for security reasons. "[Mon Nov 18 16:13:19 2013] [warn] [client 10.36.163.39] Unescaped URL path matched ProxyPass; ignoring unsafe nocanon"